# How to reference CSS children

Tags: css

I have multiply CSS `div`'s within a parent like this:

```
<div id="homepage">
     <div class="a"></div>
     <div class="b"></div>
     <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

I am currently putting this in my CSS like this:

```
#homepage .a {
     background-color: #ff0000;
}

#homepage .b {
     background-color: #0000ff;
}

#homepage .c {
     background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

My question is there a better way to reference this in my CSS than what I am currently doing. I have tried this but it fails:

```
#homepage {
     .a {
          background-color: #ff0000;
     }
     .b {
          background-color: #0000ff;
     }
     .c {
          background-color: #00ff00;
     }
}
```

Comment: that 2nd way you can use a css precompiler like less.

Comment: I thought about doing sass but I just wondered if there was a simple way to do it in css it's self

Comment: Simple answer: no - unless the classes are unique. If that's the case, you can leave out the ID.

Comment: If the classes are unique, then they should be IDs, @BramVanroy.

Comment: @Shomz They should be, but that's not in all cases possible. (E.g. when specific for a template.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do such things in plain CSS. You have to use a CSS preprocessor, for example [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Example of nesting selectors in Sass:

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

It generates following CSS:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```